# next numbers of these sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

i want to know next numbers in these 4 sequence, If I want to put it more clearly, the calculation formula is more important to me. let me explain more

s1={1,4,8,15,23,34,46,61,77,96,116,...}

s2={1,2,6,11,19,28,40,53,69,86,106,...}

these 2 series have a pattern. as far as I know, the difference between the current and previous numbers is alternately incremented by +1 and +3. However, as I mentioned before, I still need the calculation formula.

s3={1,3,7,13,21,31,43,57,73,91,111,...}

s4={1,5,9,17,25,37,49,65,81,101,121,...}

for these 2 series also have a solid pattern. If we consider the number series s3, where the difference between the current and previous number is always increasing by a constant value, we can write it as:

s3' = {+2, +4, +6, +8, +10, +12, ...}

Now, if we observe this pattern, we can see that it is consistently increasing by adding the number 2

I would appreciate it if you could provide me with the formula to calculate the next number.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Looking at the differences is a good start. Let’s look at what you called $S1$. Here I will call it $S$. Let $A’$ denote the sequence of differences of a sequence $A$.

$S= 1, 4, 8, 15 …$

$S’= 3, 4, 7, 8 …$

$S’’= 1, 3, 1, 3 …$

$S’’_n= 2+ (-1)^n$

$S’_n=S’_{n-1}+(-1)^{n}+2 , S’_0=3$

$S_n=S_{n-1}+S’_{n-1} , S_0=1$

See if you can get the answer by playing around with that, then use similar techniques for the other sequences.

Comment: thank you, that was a clear answer